# How to automate the file arranging for plotter to make it efficient and faster in Corel Draw 16+

Tags: corel-draw

i need automate the file puzzling for plotter, so im looking for a macros for Corel 16+, to get the puzzling done automatically and efficiently.

In the past i puzzled it manually and spent a lot of time.

[image: a file for plotter]

I tried PlotCalc for Corel, but it doesnt work in 16th version

Thanks
PS if this topic is already asked, please, do not dislike my question)

Comment: @joojaa but that question about Illustrator, not Corel Draw macroses. I think this is must be a separate question according to stackoverflow policy, is it?

Comment: Yes, it is a separate one.

Comment: @AlexNikonov yes but svgnest does not need corel or illustrator, its standalone and so far the only nesting app that is free, for obvious reasons

Comment: Oh and theres a desktop version of svgnest that is a bit faster

Comment: @joojaa yea, you're right, but Svgnest helps with svg or pdf, but i need to leave nested objects as they are (as corel objects with embedded elements inside) in spite of the fact that ecut paid soft.

Comment: deepnest reads cdr files, but yeah if you want to pay then pay.

Comment: @joojaa i appriciate your help, i do not advocate eCut and that's paid, but i researched [Deepnest](https://deepnest.io) its UI is really cool and easy, but it doesnt support CD 17, because it fails loading this [coreldraw file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFyAi.png), more over it doesnt work in Corel environment ( i shall to save to certain CD vestion, open in Deepnest, after the nesting i ought go back to corel and place it back). It's a kinda meshing.

Answer (score 0):

I found two tools for Corel

- [PlotCalc](http://eng.plotcalc.com/)
- [eCut](http://eng.e-cut.ru/index.php)

I tried both but my favorite is eCut, because it arranges my files in more frugel way about 10% less size comparing to PlotCalc.
More over eCut support CorelDraw X3-X8, 2017, 2018